# Import Oracle DUMP file in oracle instance 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, oracle-dump

I have an oracle `.dmp` file and I do not know any other information about that, I want to import this dump file to my oracle 19c database.

When I use the `imdb` command like this:

```
impdp DIRECTORY=E:\Oracle19c\db_home\admin\sample\bdump DUMPFILE=tf20200325.dmp
```

I get these errors:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name E:\ORACLE19C\DB_HOME\ADMIN\SAMPLE\BDUMP is invalid
```

When I use the `imp` command like this:

```
imp file=E:\Oracle19c\db_home\admin\sample\bdump\tf20200325.dmp full=y;
```

I get these errors:

```
IMP-00038: Could not convert to environment character set's handle
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

I tried after searching on the web, but not found any solution to help me.

**notable**: I am not creating any databases, I only create a user with all privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory you specify is the name of a database directory object, not the actual directory. So, connect to your db as SYS, and do

```
create directory xyz as 'E:\Oracle19c\db_home\admin\sample\bdump\';
grant all on directory xyz to (put your user name);
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
impdp directory=xyz .....
```